# One question about BRST symmetry in reading Srednicki’s book: Why should the BRST charge $Q_B$ be nilpotent?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, commutator, brst, superalgebra

In p.453, Srednicki claims that since the BRST transformation of a BRST transformation is zero, $Q_B$, the BRST charge, must be nilpotent:
$$Q_{B}^{2}=0.\tag{74.32}$$
I don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

Ref. 1 claims that

> $$ \delta_B^2~=~0 \qquad \Rightarrow\qquad  Q_B^2~=~0. \tag{1}$$

Here the BRST transformation $\delta_B$ and the BRST charge $Q_B$ are related by the relation
$$ \delta_B(\cdot)~=~i[Q_B,\cdot],\tag{2}$$
where $[\cdot,\cdot]$ denotes the [supercommutator](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=supercommutator). OP asks why the implication (1) is true?

Well, that's a good question, and a lot less trivial than it superficially seems$^1$. Here is an argument. From the Jacobi identity for the supercommutator, we get
$$\begin{align} 0
~\stackrel{\text{nilp.}}{=}& -\delta_B^2(\cdot)\cr
~\stackrel{(2)}{=}~&[Q_B,[Q_B,\cdot]]\cr
~\stackrel{\text{Jac. id.}}{=}&\frac{1}{2}[[Q_B,Q_B],\cdot]\cr
~=~&[Q_B^2,\cdot].
\end{align} \tag{3}$$

So $Q_B^2$ is a Casimir operator. This in practice shows that
$$ \exists \text{ constant } k:~~ Q_B^2~=~k \mathbb{1} .\tag{4}$$

Arguments that the constant
$$k~=~0.\tag{5}$$
vanishes go as follows:

1. Because the BRST charge $Q_B$ has ghost number 1, then $k$ has ghost number 2. But most physical theories don't have any ghost number carrying constants lying around, so $k$ is zero, cf. Ref. 2.

If we are not allowed to use ghost number symmetry, here's another argument:

2. One would naively expect from eq. (4) that the constant $k$ is a [soul-valued constant](https://planetmath.org/Supernumber), but most physical theories don't have any soul-valued constants lying around, so $k$ is zero$^2$.

In practice (e.g. in Yang-Mills theory with matter), the constant $k$ indeed vanishes.

Altogether we get
$$  Q_B^2~\stackrel{(4)+(5)}{=}~0 .\tag{6}$$
$\Box$

References:

1. M. Srednicki, *QFT,* 2007; Chapter 74. A prepublication draft PDF file is available [here](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emark/qft.html).
2. J. Polchinski, *String Theory* Vol. 1, 1998; p. 128.

--

$^1$ The opposite implication ($\Leftarrow$) in eq. (1) is a triviality.

$^2$ This sentence is flawed as the following toy-example shows: $Q_B=\frac{d}{d\theta}+\theta$ leads to $k=1$.

Comment: but this just begs the question: why should the Slavnov differential be nilpotent?

Comment: Right, that's a good but bigger question, which is answered in e.g. Henneaux & Teitelboim. The short answer is: By appropriate construction, cf. the proof of the existence of a nilpotent BRST charge, chapter 9 & 10.

Comment: @Alessio Fontanarossa: Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If applying any  map $A$  twice gives zero, then $A^2=0$ by definition of what is meant by $A^2$.  How can it be different here?

Comment: But doing a BRST transformation is not just same as simply multiplying a $Q_{B}$?

Comment: $Q^2$ is not just zero when acting as a commutator. It has to be zero when it acts twice on any *state*. You can start from this statement, and use the (super)-jacobi identity to deduce the the double (super)-commutator with any operator must vanish, so $\delta^2=0$ as well.